# Excel transpor linha para coluna e preserva colunas e replicá-las em linha

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, vba, csv

Olá,

Seguinte , tenho um CSV da seguinte forma:

```
A;B;C;D;1;2;3;4;5

E;F;G;H;6;7;8;9;10
```

As colunas de letras possuem uma estrutura regular, já as de numero não
mas poderia explodi-las e coloca-las em colunas porem, não vai ter como criar á métrica desejada

Mas ao transpor na minha imaginação ficaria assim:

```
A;B;C;D;2

A;B;C;D;3
```

E assim por diante!

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tentar usar o colar especial. Copie as células que deseje e aperte Ctrl + Alt + V, caso queira transpor marque a opção de transpor células.

Comment: Perfeito, porem é uma planilha gigantesca!, ela do jeito q está já tem 10k linhas, ao transpor , vai ter 1 linha q vai virar 30 linhas ou até mais, por isso estou atras de algo mais automatizado!

Comment: Só criar a macro a qual publiquei na outra resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho a usar essa macro a qual fiz, será feito tudo automaticamente, só criar a macro e executar. Caso a linha não esteja na A1, é só mudar o local da linha dentro da macro.

```
Sub Transpor()

    'Transpor Linha
    contalinha = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set BigArray = Cells(1, 1).Resize(contalinha, 1)
    Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, contalinha).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BigArray)
    BigArray.Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Solução perfeita

```
Sub CONVERTROWSTOCOL_Oeldere_revisted_new()

    Dim rsht1 As Long, rsht2 As Long, i As Long, col As Long, wsTest As Worksheet, mr As Worksheet, ms As Worksheet

    'check if sheet "ouput" already exist

    Const strSheetName As String = "Output"

    Set wsTest = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsTest Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName
    End If

    'set the data


    Set mr = Sheets("sheet1")                    'this is the name of the source sheet

    Set ms = Sheets("Output")                    'this is the name of the destiny sheet

    col = 2
    'End set the data

    With ms
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        .Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Mat", "value")
    End With

    rsht2 = ms.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    With mr
        rsht1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To rsht1
            Do While .Cells(1, col).Value <> ""  'And .Cells(I, col).Value <> ""
                rsht2 = rsht2 + 1

                ms.Range("A" & rsht2).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value


                ms.Range("B" & rsht2).Value = .Cells(i, col).Value

                col = col + 1
            Loop
            col = 2
        Next
    End With

    With ms
        .Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Criei o código abaixo pelo exemplo que você deu.

Mude o Worksheets(1) e Worksheets(2) conforme a planilha com a origem e a planilha que servirá de destino.

```
Public Sub Replica()
Dim linha As Range
Dim Celula As Range
Dim Atributos As String
Dim Metricas As String
NumeroLinha = 1
For Each linha In Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows
    Atributos = ""
    Metricas = ""
    For Each Celula In linha.Cells
        If TypeName(Celula.Value) = "String" And Celula.Value <> "" Then
        Atributos = IIf(Atributos = "", Celula.Value, Atributos & ";" & Celula.Value)
    Else
        Metricas = IIf(Metricas = "", Celula.Value, Metricas & ";" & Celula.Value)
    End If
Next Celula
AtributosArray = Split(Atributos, ";")
MetricasArray = Split(Metricas, ";")
For i = 0 To UBound(MetricasArray)
    Worksheets(2).Rows(NumeroLinha).Resize(, UBound(AtributosArray) + 1).FormulaArray = AtributosArray
    Worksheets(2).Cells(NumeroLinha, UBound(AtributosArray) + 2) = MetricasArray(i)
    NumeroLinha = NumeroLinha + 1
Next i
Next linha
End Sub
```